# How to get value of CheckBoxList items other than text

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, checkboxlist

I am a simple webforms which has CheckBoxList with multiple selection and i want to get value of items rather than text.

```
 <asp:CheckBoxList ID="ChkAreaOfInterest" runat="server" CssClass="row-dd" >
    <asp:ListItem Value="0" Selected="True">---SELECT OPTION--</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="One">RED</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="Two">GREEN</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="Three">BLUE</asp:ListItem>
</asp:CheckBoxList>
```

I use below code to get the value but it gets me text of the Items

```
List<ListItem> selectedInterest = new List<ListItem>();
foreach (ListItem item in ChkAreaOfInterest.Items)
if (item.Selected) selectedInterest.Add(item);
string sCheckedValue = string.Join(",", selectedInterest);
```

Comment: Just a 0.39 second of googling for _"C# CheckBoxList"_ and another couple of seconds for reading give me this: `var sCheckedValue = string.Join(",", ChkAreaOfInterest.Items.Where(i => i.Selected).Select(i => i.Value));`

Comment: @ i am getting error for this `System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItemsCollection does not contain a defination for Where.....`

Comment: oh, sure, just a little more LINQ: `var sCheckedValue = string.Join(",", ChkAreaOfInterest.Items.OfType<ListItem>().Where(i => i.Selected).Select(i => i.Value));`

Comment: @vasily.sib, Yes it worked, could you post it as answer so that i can mark it as correct answer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you `string.Join(",", selectedInterest)` - runtime will call `.ToString()` on every item in `selectedInterest` which in fact returns value of `.Text` property.

Instead you need to join `ListItem.Value` properties values. This can be done with LINQ:

```
var selectedInterest = ChkAreaOfInterest.Items.OfType<ListItem>().Where(i => i.Selected);
var sCheckedValue = string.Join(",", selectedInterest.Select(i => i.Value));
```

Answer (score 0):

why can't you try this

```
 List<string> selectedInterest = new List<string>();
 for (int i = 0; i < ChkAreaOfInterest.Items.Count - 1; i++ )
 {
     if (ChkAreaOfInterest.Items[i].Selected)
     {
        selectedInterest.Add(ChkAreaOfInterest.Items[i].Value);
     }
 }
```